# chrome js console: can I use it as ES6 react js component in desktop JS application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome-devtools

Is any way to have my own instance of Chrome console as react component in my **desktop** application. Being **desktop** application assumes that to have my application up and running

- I will use Chrome
- I can write and install Chrome plugins.
- I can build my own browser based on framework like CEF C# https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/ or https://electronjs.org

The code to illustrate what I am looking for on JS script side of my application:

```
class App extends Component {
 constructor() {
   super();
   this.logger_one = null;
   this.logger_two = null;
 }

 render() {
  return (<div>
             <SomeOtherComponent .../>
             <ChromeConsole ref={(r)=>{this.logger_one = r}} />
             <hr/>
             <ChromeConsole ref={(r)=>{this.logger_two = r}} />
          </div>
           )
 }

 event_handler_one() {
   logger_one.log("something happen for one...");
 }

 event_handler_two() {
   logger_two.log("something happen for two...");
 }
}
```

`this.logger_one` and `this.logger_two` suppose to refer to instances of an object like **console** so I can use this API: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/console/console-reference

I need to get a reference to Chrome console instances, not custom-made console replacement. It is important since I do need all that nice features available for js developers but for a different purpose - observation and understanding my system behavior.

Comment: "certain events" like what?

Comment: Well not an actual instance of Chrome console but you can copy it's functionality... an example of this is the console div in the Stack Snippets feature on this site

Comment: @PatrickEvans i was unable to follow your hint. the question will have bounty so please elaborate. I need to have multiple loggers in my app main window with somewhat elaborate functionality. just having textarea instances is an initial option only.

Comment: Yes, it's obviously possible to create a component that displays strings prettily based on some state. Are you asking for a library recommendation, hoping someone will write one for you, or do you have a specific question?

Comment: @Jonas Høgh -- 'library recommendation, hoping someone will write one for you' -- yes, component I can 'npm install' to my react project

Comment: That is unfortunately considered off-topic here on SO - see https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @Jonas Høgh copy-paste of code works also.

Comment: npm install terminal-in-react 
import Terminal from 'terminal-in-react';
<Terminal watchConsoleLogging />

This will log all the console.log messages. 
Just a thought,a filter function can be passed to Terminal which will filter the logs.

Comment: component documentation at https://github.com/nitin42/terminal-in-react

Comment: You can't get a satisfactory answer with a question like that. You can't use Chrome console without Chrome console, especially the features that aren't available in client-side JS because of security limitations. It's unclear what 'nice features' exactly you're talking about but if you believe they can be implemented in client-side JS and you have problems implementing them yourself, consider reasking the question and addressing them one by one.

Comment: @estus thanks for mentioning client-side JS. I updated the question. I need desktop intranet app with no connection to internet. So i can easily install Chrome plugins or move to framework like electron - if it helps to have Chrome consoles working as described in the question.

Answer (score 2):

*NOTES*

- The `window.console` object is a native implementation that can not be **instantiated** as there's no **constructor function** or **class** available. But that is fine, because your "two" loggers can use the same `window.console` without a problem.
- The structure `<ChromeConsole ref={(r)=>{this.logger_one = r}} />` will store in `this.logger_one` a reference to the DOM JSX element ([See Refs on React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#callback-refs)), so it will not be a reference that we can manipulate. But that is fine, because we can use any other attribute.

---

You can use a functional component to define a property (example `console`) and use it to return the window console:

```
export default const ChromeConsole = ({ id, console }) => {
  console(window.console);
  return (<div data-logger-id={id} />);
}
```

Use it then as:

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.logger_one = null;
    this.logger_two = null;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <SomeOtherComponent .../>
        <ChromeConsole id="one" console={(r)=>{this.logger_one = r}} />
        <button onClick={event_handler_one} />
        <hr/>
        <ChromeConsole id="two" console={(r)=>{this.logger_two = r}} />
        <button onClick={event_handler_two} />
      </div>
    );
  }

  event_handler_one = () => {
    this.logger_one.log("something happen for one...");
  }

  event_handler_two = () => {
    this.logger_two.log("something happen for two...");
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is my proposition:

```
<div id="log"></div>
<input id="command" onkeyup="handleCmdEnter(event,this)"/>
```

And js:

```
var old = console.log;
var logger = document.getElementById('log');

console.log = function (message) {
  if (typeof message == 'object') {
    logger.innerHTML += (JSON && JSON.stringify ? JSON.stringify(message) : message) + '<br />';
  } else {
    logger.innerHTML += message + '<br />';
  }
}

window.handleCmdEnter = (event, input) => {
  if(event.key=='Enter'){
      let val = input.value;
      input.value ='';
      logger.innerHTML+='<br>'+val;      

      try {
        let res = eval(val);
        logger.innerHTML+='<br>'+res;  
      } catch (e) {
        old({e});
        logger.innerHTML+='<br>EXCEPTION:'+e.message;
        logger.innerHTML+='<br>Stacktrace:'+e.stack;
      }
  } 
}

console.log('xxx');
```

And here is [working example](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqubsxd2/1/).

This solution doesn't include styles and use 'eval' (=evil) function. It's override "console.log" function (you can override other console functions like `error`, `debug`,... and also intercepts more console parameters using `arguments`).

I only give base idea above how to do it, it needs to be developed (as js library) to have more functionality but StackOverflow is go place to put such code.

Comment: well, but i do need Chrome console. I've updated the question. Sorry for confusion